# macOS 11.1 - Python launcher crashes

Tags: python, macos, crash, launcher

Python launcher crashes since upgrading to macOS 11.1 - I have checked that I am on the latest version of Python 3.

I get the error `macOS 11 or later required ! Abort trap: 6`

Answer (score 0):

I had to install MacOS Python package directly from python.org - it wouldn't work otherwise.